# Simplest route with a variable and a string? -- Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a `store` model with the following:

```
  def to_param
    slug + "-info"
  end
```

The urls will be like:

```
/dell-info
/ibm-info
/apple-info
```

My route for this is clearly wrong:

```
match '/:slug-info' => 'stores#info', :as => :stores
```

How can I fix this? If I use `match '/:slug(-info)'` as the route it works but matches BOTH `/dell` and `/dell-info`

Comment: Why not make `info` another store action, and use `/:slug/info`?

Comment: Due to a business requirement to have the simplest url without any nesting.

Comment: Well, okay, but IMO that just confuses things by introducing a non-standard separator. It's still nesting, you're just changing what character is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add some constraints to the route and then strip off the "-info" in your controller:

```
match '/:slug' => 'stores#info', :as => :stores, :constraints => { :slug => /-info$/ }
```

and then, in your controller:

```
def info
  slug = params[:slug].sub(/-info$/, '')
  #...
end
```

Or better, have a method on your model that can remove the "-info" suffix while it looks up an object based on the slug:

```
# In the model
def self.for_slug(slug)
  slug = slug.sub(/-info$/, '')
  find_by_slug(slug)
end

# In the controller
def info
  thing = Thing.for_slug(params[:slug])
  #...
end
```